# php write hebrew / UTF-8 in csv

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, hebrew

Hi I am trying to write a CSV with HEBREW text in it. It writes some symbol not an Hebrew text. Below is my PHP CODE.

```
<?php
    $list = array (
                array('שלטל', 'שלטל', 'שלטל', 'שלטל'),
                array('123', '456', '789'),
                array('"שלטל"', '"שלטל"')
            );
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
            //fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
            foreach ($list as $fields) {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }
     fclose($fp);
?>
```

I checked in internet and added "**fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ))**" but it didnt work out. Can some one help me.

Below is the out put i am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran your code. The text is correctly encoded and generated csv is valid. Opening the CSV in a text editor that supports Hebrew text will show correctly. To open CSV containing Hebrew you need to follow instructions as suggested [here](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0)

**Update:**

So turns out MS uses UTF-16 and not only that it uses UTF-16LE (little endian). For MS CSV to open correctly, you need UTF-16LE encoded text, tab delimited file.

```
$list = array (
            array('שלטל', 'שלטל', 'שלטל', 'שלטל'),
            array('123', '456', '789'),
            array('"שלטל"', '"שלטל"')
        );

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

//UTF-16LE BOM
fputs($fp, chr(0xFF) . chr(0xFE));

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    $out = '';
    foreach ($fields as $k => $v){
        $fields[$k] = mb_convert_encoding($v, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');          
    }

    // UTF-16LE tab
    $out = implode(chr(0x09).chr(0x00), $fields);

    // UTF-16LE new line
    fputs($fp, $out.chr(0x0A).chr(0x00));
}
fclose($fp);
```

Above code works, not sure about its efficiency though.

Comment: But when i use Codeigniter "PHPExcel" The output come in Hebrew without changing any settings. So i need such solutions. U know we cant tell all the users to follow the steps to see the data! Is there any other way??

Comment: @TomPHP so after a lot of playing around, i believe i have a solution. update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've encountered this before and sometimes some versions of excel just isn't showing proper utf8 characters/fonts. but the file itself have utf8 already.

Try opening your csv into Notepad++ and see if it is a utf8-bom and if its showing utf8 characters

Comment: nope its not working with BOM.. I tried already.. Also i cant insist all users to user Nodepad++ because the default software they will have are ms-excell installed.. So I am looking for a solution to open it in msoffice ..

Comment: No need to insist user to use npp. I mentioned it so you can check it once using it. anyway, you found a solution! Way to go!

Answer (score -1):

Try this alternative saving as CSV:

```
$data = "שם פרטי,שם משפחה,עיר\na,b,c\n1,2,3";           // need to use  " for \n
file_put_contents("myexcel.csv","\xEF\xBB\xBF");      // BOM with UTF-8 to csv
file_put_contents("myexcel.csv",$data,FILE_APPEND);   // add more data
```

Hope it helps.